# Rails order by existence of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by

Imagine the following tables:

> class Fan < ActiveRecord::Base
>     has_many :fan_influencers
>   end
>
> class Influencer < ActiveRecord::Base
>     has_many :fan_influencers
>   end

I want a method that given a fan returns all influencers sorted by whether the fan has a relation with that influencer. This means that the influencers that have a fan_influencers relation with the fan will appear first. 
How can I do that? I have this method in the influencer model but it doesn't depend on the fan:

> def self.index_results_for_fan(fan)
>
> Influencer.includes(:fan_influencers).order('fan_influencers.influencer_id NULLS LAST')
>
> end

This is part of a more complex method (that orders by other fields and uses union with other queries, etc).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Influencer
  .includes(:fan_influencers)
  .where(fan_id: fan.id)
  .order('fan_influencers.influencer_id NULLS LAST')
```

I guess you have Fan's foreign key in fan_influencers as it is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: That's a good idea although there you are only getting the ones that actually have a relation with the fan, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that once you get to a certain level of complexity, if you're comfortable with SQL then you're better off creating a view that encapsulates that complexity (like the existence of records in other tables, and joins, and unions).

Create a model on top of the view, make it read only, and relate it to other models through associations.

This will simplify your Rails code enormously.

Comment: I was avoiding raw sql for other reasons in the query. I just ended up doing two different Active record relations and use the union gem to join them using a sort key to keep the order.